# Couldn't canonicalise: No such file or directory

Tags: unix, sftp

I am getting `Couldn't canonicalise: No such file or directory` error while getting single file using sftp.
here is what I am doing,

```
#!/bin/ksh
. /feeds/scripts/files.properties

filename=$1.txt

echo $filename  

sftp $getusername@$getserver << EOF >> $logfile

cd /feeds/out/data/

lcd /feeds/files/

get $filename

bye

EOF
```

I am able to print/echo file name, but while executing scripts I am getting below error,

```
user:/feeds/scripts> ./fileReceiver.sh sample
sample.txt
Connecting to xxxxx.xxx.xxx...
Couldn't canonicalise: No such file or directory
Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory
File "/u/user/sample.txt" not found.
```

I don't know why it adds '/u/user' before file name. Can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7004/uploading-directories-with-sftp) might help.

Comment: Solved!,
I am sorry, my mistake. In property file, I had mentioned wrong server name. Server names looks very similar so couldn't figure it out.
Anyways, thanks @devnull, I gone through it, its useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!, I am sorry, my mistake. In property file, I had mentioned wrong server name. Server names looks very similar so couldn't figure it out. Anyways, thanks @devnull, I gone through it, its useful.

Answer (score 0):

For me solution was removing / from directory name at end

Non-working

```
/folder-name/
```

Working

```
/folder-name
```